# parse row values as columns and use to lookup values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to parse row values as columns and use them to look up values in a pandas dataframe

tried iterrows and .loc indexing without success

```
import pandas as pd

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
```

build toy dataset

```
coltable = StringIO("""NA;NB;NC;ND;pair;desired_result
10;60;50;20;NANB;70
20;30;10;5;NANC;30
40;30;20;10;NCND;30

""")
df = pd.read_csv(coltable, sep=";")
```

I want to access the column elements of the pair (eg first row NA=10 and NB=60 and use those values to create a new column (desired_result=10+60=70).

I want the function to create the new column in pandas to be compatible with np.vectorize as the dataset is huge

Something like this:

```
df['newcol'] = np.vectorize(myfunc)(pair=df['pair'])
```

thanks a lot for any assistance you can give!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
a = df.lookup(df.index, df['pair'].str[:2])
b = df.lookup(df.index, df['pair'].str[2:])

df['new'] = a + b
print (df)
   NA  NB  NC  ND  pair  desired_result  new
0  10  60  50  20  NANB              70   70
1  20  30  10   5  NANC              30   30
2  40  30  20  10  NCND              30   30
```

Also if no missing values is possible use list comprehension or apply:

```
#repeat dataframe 10000 times
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [263]: %%timeit
     ...: a = df.lookup(df.index, df['pair'].str[:2])
     ...: b = df.lookup(df.index, df['pair'].str[2:])
     ...: 
     ...: df['new'] = a + b
     ...: 
59.5 ms ± 2.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [264]: %%timeit
     ...: a = df.lookup(df.index, [x[:2] for x in df['pair']])
     ...: b = df.lookup(df.index, [x[2:] for x in df['pair']])
     ...: 
     ...: df['new'] = a + b
     ...: 
60.8 ms ± 963 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [265]: %%timeit
     ...: a = df.lookup(df.index, df['pair'].apply(lambda x: x[:2]))
     ...: b = df.lookup(df.index, df['pair'].apply(lambda x: x[2:]))
     ...: 
     ...: df['new'] = a + b
     ...: 
     ...: 
56.6 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: great thanks @jezrael, this is what I will use. Do you know if a vectorized numpy based solution is possible?

Comment: @MichaelK - I think not, because most numpy based functions are already vectorized.